# Stripe integrations fetch return cors error 400

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

redirected: false
​
status: 400
​
statusText: "Bad Request"
​
type: "cors"
​
url: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers"

return this error.

```
    let customer= {
            "name": "xxxxxx",
            "phone": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "email": "sxxxxxxa@gmail.com",
            "description": "test account "
        }

        let url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers';

        let body = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/form-data',
                'Authorization':'Bearer sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'Stripe-Version': '2014-12-22',
            },
            //body: JSON.stringify(customer),
//json:true
            body: customer
        }

        let response = await fetch(url, body);
        console.log("response ",response.type)
        if (response.ok) {
            let json = await response.json();
        } else {
            console.log("err",response)
        }
```

Comment: Rather than going down the potential rabbit hole of building requests manually, I'd recommend using the [Stripe libraries](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries). If you can't use those libraries for some reason, see [how stripe-node builds requests](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/1d6207e34f978d8709d42d8a05d7d7e8be6599c7/lib/StripeResource.js#L311) as a working example.

Comment: What is `application/form-data`?

Answer (score 1):

Stripe docs says the request was unacceptable - 400 bad request is often due to missing a required parameter, so check the API docs from here and check what is missing:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

Answer (score 0):

I've often found one of the fastest and most effective ways to debug problems with Stripe is by using the developer tools they provide, in particular the [logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs). For example, when I ran into this particular problem Stripe let me know that a parameter I was passing it (`amount` in my case) had become null - once I fixed this, my "bad request" errors disappeared.

Stuff like this is why Stripe are known for their developer experience, so it makes sense to to take advantage of it wherever possible and minimise the time you spend losing sleep and hair over an issue.